# Sending room code from server side to client side - Socket.io, Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, backend

Newbie at web dev here. I am trying to create rooms with randomly generated codes using socket.io for users to connect with.

My goal is to have the URL looking something like this when a user is connected into a room:

`localhost:3000/room/ABCDE`

Here is the post request code from the server.js file. When the user presses one of the two buttons (Create or Join). I use the data in the `req` parameter to hold onto the room code entered.
`/room` here is the namespace.

```
app.post("/room", function(req,res){
  
  //Check to see if the req is authenticated
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){

    //Check if create button room button was pressed
    //If so create new room, push it to array and enter the room

    if (req.body.buttonType === "create"){
      var newCode = generateRoomCode()
      activeRoomCodes.push(newCode);
      res.redirect("/room/"+newCode);
    }

    //Else check to see if the room already exists and is active then
    //Join the room

    else{
      if (activeRoomCodes.includes(req.body.roomcode)){
        res.redirect("/room/"+req.body.roomcode)
      }

      //Else prompt the user that the room doesn't exist and redirect them

      else{
        //ALERT USER ROOM DOESN'T EXIST
        res.redirect("/room")
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Below is the socket.io connection on the server side, also in the server.js file

```
//Create "/room" namespace and upon connection add user into the room
io.of("/room").on("connection", function(socket){

 //Check if room exists and add user to room
  socket.on("joinRoom", function(room){
    console.log(room)
      if(activeRoomCodes.includes(room)){
          socket.join(room)
          io.of("/test").in(room).emit("newUser", "New User has joined "+ room)
          socket.emit("success", "You have successfully joined "+ room)
          console.log("Server Message: New User has joined "+room)
      }
      else{
          socket.emit("err", "No room named "+room)
      }
      
  })

  // socket.disconnect()

})
```

Finally here is the client side `app.js` file

```
const io = require("socket.io-client");
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000/room")

socket.emit("joinRoom", "<ROOM CODE GOES HERE>")

socket.on("newUser", function(msg){
    console.log(msg)
})

socket.on("err", function(msg){
    console.log(msg)
})

socket.on("success", function(msg){
    console.log(msg)
})
```

I need to get the room code into the `app.js` file from the `server.js` file but I can't seem to figure out how. I got it to work by combining the code from client side and the server side into on file but I don't think that's a good idea. Any suggestions?

Note: The form which takes in the user input to join a room and the create room button are on an EJS file